# My Android App is not working with \n in TextView

Tags: android, xml, data-binding, textview

Dear all if anyone can help me with this then it will be greatfull. because from past 2 days i'm struggling with My Android App is not working with \n in TextView.

This is my databse text.

[image]

This is my Adapter Java code:
[image]

in the Design XML part, it's working but in data binding it's not working.you can see in the design.
[image]

Comment: Remove `Html.fromHtml`

Comment: in starting i used this but didn't work.